# simple timer, starting from 0 to whatever number

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to make a simple timer, starting  from 0 to whatever number.I want to interrup the timer when I press a button.
I've done this so far, I'n not interested about the button part yet.When I run, I don't get anything displayed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;




/*lista clienti care asteapta
avem timer->creaza action event care il tratam in action performed--crestem timpul simu;larii cu 1 in action performed,apoi parcurgem lista de clienti care ast si verificam care clienti au timpul de arival = timpul simulatrii
--fiecare client e distribuit la una din cozi-for pt fiecare client. gasim coada cu timpul min de asteptare si il adaugam acolo--tot in action performed
daca timpul de servire a ajun l;a 0  clientul e scos din coada
 */
public class Magazin extends JFrame{
    //protected ArrayList<Clienti> arrayClienti = new ArrayList<Clienti>();


    public Magazin(){

    }
    class event implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count = 0;
            count++;
                TimeClass tc=new TimeClass(count);
                Timer timer= new Timer(1000,tc);
                timer.start();
            //System.out.println(count+"sec:");
        }

    }
    class TimeClass implements ActionListener{
    int counter;
        public TimeClass(int counter){
            this.counter=counter;           
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent tc) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("sec:"+counter);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Main class I have this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

         new Magazin(); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and display a top-level window for something to be visible, this means that since you're using a JFrame, somewhere in code you'll need a main method, and that somewhere in code that is called, you'll need:

```
Magazin magazin = new Magazin(); // create your JFrame
magazin.setVisible(true);  // display it.
```

I don't see a main method anywhere or your setting a JFrame visible. You've got other problems as well, but this is the first step you'll need for creating a visible GUI.

Some other issues:

- You've got an ArrayList of something, Clienti, that is never used.
- You've got no component, such as a JLabel, displaying your Time.
- Your Timer's ActionListener creates a new JFrame -- why would it want to do that?
- Your Magazin class has an actionPerformed method -- why? It's not acting as an ActionListener and does not implement ActionListener.

You will want to study the Swing tutorials to better understand how to use these tools. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)